# What is the reason of putting measure_vars before id_vars in Julia DataFrame's stack function?

Tags: dataframe, julia

While `stack`-ing DataFrame, i.e. converting it from wide to long format, usually you specify `id_vars` - the column(s) you need to be repeated (index), and all other columns (`measure_vars`, e.g. observations) are stacked in one long column.

But in Julia DataFrames, those arguments are specified not as named keywords, and `measure_vars` come before `id_vars` in function call.

What is the reason for such placement of arguments? How do I specify `id_vars` without `measure_vars`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the reason for such placement of arguments?

There are following considerations:

1. you must have `measure_vars` to perform stacking, while it is possible to perform `stack` without `id_vars` (by default if you omit `id_vars` these are taken as all columns other than `measure_vars`); technically you can do `stack` without `measure_vars` (see my comment below - but it is not very useful I think)
2. backward compatibility (we do not want to be breaking, and a long time ago this was the approach that was originally used, because keyword arguments were slow, which is not the case any more)

> How do I specify `id_vars` without `measure_vars`?

Just write `stack(df, [], id_vars)`, but this is not something that is super useful.

On the other hand if you want to specify `measure_vars` as all columns except some columns that you want to be `id_vars` then write: `stack(df, Not(id_vars))`.

Comment: I somehow expected to specify `id_vars` only and have remaining columns as `measure_vars`. Anyways, thanks for the tip with `Not(id_vars)`. I am sure I've seen it in examples or help!

Comment: This was in the past with `melt`, but we decided to retain only one function, as everyone kept forgetting the argument order of `stack` vs `melt`. We removed it as we judged that using `Not` should be easy enough in practice.